# Can a sequence of polynomials in a translation invariant linear space pointwise converge to a polynomial which is not included in that space? In one variable this is impossible. 

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Can a sequence of polynomials in a translation invariant linear space (of polynomials, of course) point-wise converge to a polynomial which is not included in that space? In one variable this is impossible.

Comment: A sequence of polynomials converges point-wise to a polynomial if and only if it converges coefficient-wise to it. A linear space of polynomials is translation invariant if and only if it is invariant under partial differentiation. 

Comment: The first claim is true only if the degrees are uniformly bounded. 

Comment: (precisely, point-wise convergence implies coefficient-wise convergence, but not the opposite, as the example $x^n$ shows).

Comment: (Pietro Majer) Yeah, sorry.

Comment: Erm, the pointwise convergence doesn't imply the coefficient-wise one either.

Comment: Coefficients are linear combinations of derivatives, derivatives are linear combinations of differences, differences are linear combinations of function values - hence point-wise convergence does imply coefficient-wise convergence.

Comment: This question seems to me really interesting. I don't understand why it got one vote only. Would it meet with more success if the OP re-edited it and add some more details and motivation? 

Comment: a) You can approximate $x$ by linear combinations of $x^2,x^3,\dots$ uniformly on arbitrarily large intervals, so, no, pointwise convergence does not imply the coefficientwise one. b) It is a nice problem, indeed, but I made it a rule not to answer to unknown(yahoo)'s. If the OP creates a unique username, I'll think of the question and vote it up.